# What is the rationale behind std::make_[un]signed to copy cv but not ref qualifiers

Tags: c++, std, type-traits, ref-qualifier

While trying to implement a `make_signed_with_fallback` for non integral types i noticed that `std::make_[un]signed` is designed to copy `cv` but not `ref` qualifiers and I'm wondering why.

The only explanation I can think of is that copying `ref` qualifiers is only rarely needed.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any standard machinery to copy `cv` or `ref` qualifiers from one to another type, and the only thing i could find is private in the `type_traits` headers ([ms](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/type_traits#L1301), [clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L1921), [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L1631)) which makes me think that that's not very common either.

I found a [old question on SO about the implementation of a copy cv ref trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171682/type-trait-for-copying-cv-reference-qualifiers) though.

Comment: noteworthy: `std::is_integral_v<int> == true` while `std::is_integral_v<int&> == false`